# Ble device is not pairing consistently to phone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a ble device that I need to regularly extract data from securely and constantly. So on startup I want to make sure to bond the device if it is not already. I have the Mac address of the device in this case.

```
public void startApp(){
    remoteDevice = bluetoothManager.getAdapter().getRemoteDevice(MAC_AD);
    if(remoteDevice.getBondState()!=12){
        remoteDevice.createBond();
    }
}
```

What ends up happening is that the bond state will alternate between unbonded and currently_bonding but not fully bond.

The strange thing is that sometimes it will work, but usually not, particularly on my google pixel. Bonding through the settings is also very inconsistent.

Is there any way to retry this or some kind of Bluetooth reset that should be done so that I can bond consistently?

I've tried calling createBond() in intervals;

Comment: Check the HCI log or use an air sniffer to see why the bonding fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've often found that calling `createBond()` directly can have hit-and-miss results depending on the platform (both ends). Logically it should use the same mechanism internally, but I've tended to get better results by calling read on a simple characteristic which has bonded requirements.

It either successes - meaning your connection is bonded - and you can continue. Or it fails, which internally triggers the bonding, and then you can try again after a short delay, at which point it should now be bonded.

Comment: Well, the device itself officially doesn't support bonding and connectGatt() is called under the hood by a provided sdk. I don't think reading characteristics will bond the device.